# Unexpected keyword argument 'noise_model'

Tags: python, quantum-computing, qiskit

The following code throws an error. Based on some issues that I read on qiskit github, it seems that it has something do with run configs vs. compile configs but I could not find any other info that will help me resolve this issue.

```py
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, IBMQ, execute
from qiskit import BasicAer as Aer
from qiskit.providers.aer import noise


ckt = QuantumCircuit(2, 2)
ckt.h(0)
ckt.cx(0, 1)
ckt.measure(0, 0)
ckt.measure(1, 1)

qsim = Aer.get_backend("qasm_simulator")

IBMQ.load_account()
provider = IBMQ.get_provider(hub="ibm-q")
qc = provider.get_backend("ibmqx2")

props = qc.properties()
coupling_map = qc.configuration().coupling_map
noise_model = noise.device.basic_device_noise_model(props)

job = execute(
    ckt, 
    qsim, 
    noise_model=noise_model, 
    coupling_map=coupling_map, 
    basis_gates=noise_model.basis_gates
)
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-2f987d65d1f7> in <module>
     25     noise_model=noise_model,
     26     coupling_map=coupling_map,
---> 27     basis_gates=noise_model.basis_gates
     28 )

~/.venvs/qk/lib/python3.7/site-packages/qiskit/execute.py in execute(experiments, backend, basis_gates, coupling_map, backend_properties, initial_layout, seed_transpiler, optimization_level, pass_manager, qobj_id, qobj_header, shots, memory, max_credits, seed_simulator, default_qubit_los, default_meas_los, schedule_los, meas_level, meas_return, memory_slots, memory_slot_size, rep_time, parameter_binds, **run_config)
    220 
    221     # executing the circuits on the backend and returning the job
--> 222     return backend.run(qobj, **run_config)

TypeError: run() got an unexpected keyword argument 'noise_model'
```

#### Env:

- macOS 10.14.6
- Python 3.7.3
- qiskit 0.12.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is coming up because you are using BasicAer to retrieve the simulator backend. I do not think this will work with the BasicAer provider. You should be using the Aer provider.

```
from qiskit import Aer
qsim = Aer.get_backend('qasm_simulator')
```

If you just change your import statement from

```
from qiskit import BasicAer as Aer
```

to

```
from qiskit import Aer
```

then your code should work

Comment: Thank you! That was the problem.